# How to sort excel sheets in alphabetical order?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I find [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1179146/how-do-i-reorder-sheets-in-specific-order-then-alphabetically) but I am not able to find only the alphabetical sorting part.

How can I semplify that?

Answer (score 0):

In The Excel workbook that you want to organise, open VBA (alt+F11), insert a new module (insert>module) and copy and paste the following macro code:

```
Sub Sort_Active_Book()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
'
'
   iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) _
     & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", _
     vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'
' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
'
         If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
'
' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
'
         ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

Close and return to Excel, then run the macro (alt+F8). This will show a dialogue box giving you the option to sort alphabetically in ascending or descending order.

Credit to HowToGeek for this one. I found it a few months ago while being hounded by my (computer illiteriate) boss.

Hope it helps.

Edit: Make sure you save it as a 'Macro-Enabled Workbook' if you want to save the macro for further use in the spreadsheet!